# Are you missing an Assembly Reference? Canvas in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, canvas, visual-studio-code

I've just started using Linux to learn code, and am trying to make a program in Visual Studio Code, in c#. I don't really know what I'm doing, and cannot for the life of me find a tutorial or thread to help me. I am trying to make a canvas in c#, but every time I try, I am either missing an assembly reference or something does not exist in the current context. I am trying to use System.Windows.Forms, or System.Windows, I do not quite know which one is which. Can someone help me? And if it isn't too much to ask, can someone explain to me how to even use Canvas, or give me a link to some documentation? Because I can't find anything online for some reason.

```css
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project {
  
    public class program {
    
      public static void Main() {
        mainWindow = new Window();
        mainWindow.Title = 'Canvas Sample";
        
        myParentCanvas = new Canvas();
        myParentCanvas.Width = 400;
        myParentCanvas.Height = 400;
        
        myCanvas1 = new Canvas();
        myCanvas1.Background = Brushes.Red;
        myCanvas1.Height = 100;
        myCanvas1.Width = 100;
        Canvas.SetTop(myCanvas1, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(myCanvas1, 0);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: On Linux, you're either using Mono or .NET Core. Win Form support is never really completed in Mono, and there's no plan for .NET Core to ever support it. Find different tutorials focused on .NET Core or Mono.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show is from a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) sample I think.  WPF is a C# framework for building desktop user interface applications, but only on Windows.  This code will not run on Linux.

Windows Forms (WinForms) is another C# user interface framework.  There is no canvas in WinForms as far as I'm aware, and in any case the main Microsoft version of WinForms doesn't work on Linux either.  As @Martheen says, there is a version of WinForms in a thing called Mono, but it's never worked very well.  In any case, there's still no canvas I think.

The real problem you have here is that if you want to use C# there is NO Microsoft technology for building desktop user interface applications on Linux.  There are some third-party offerings, but if you're learning they are probably not the place to start.  This is why you can't find any tutorials.

You CAN build web applications that run in a browser with C# on Linux in VS Code using ASP.NET Core.  There's even an HTML5 Canvas you can use.  There are some quite good tutorials for this if you search, although they tend to use Visual Studio 2019 on Windows and you may need a separate tutorial to set up Visual Studio Code.

However, if all you want to do is to learn to code then I would start with simple console applications and don't worry too much about user interfaces and canvasses.  There are some good basic tutorials for C# if you search that don't build user interfaces at all.